# Datatables for Edit/Delete Button (Codeigniter) - Pass Parameter on href tag

Tags: codeigniter, datatable, edit

Anyone knows how I can pass id of the row to be edited/deleted? I can't seem to figure it out.

Controller:

public function branch_page()
     {

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->model('insertBranch_model');
  // Datatables Variables

$draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
$start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
$length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

$query = $this->db->select('branchCode,branchName,email,phone,date_created, CONCAT(address1, " ", address2, " ", address3) AS address',FALSE)
                ->where('status','active')
                ->get('branchdetails');

$data = [];

foreach($query->result() as $r) {
   $data[] = array(
            $r->branchCode,
            $r->branchName,
            $r->address,
            $r->email,
            $r->phone,
            $r->date_created,
            $r->href='<a href="editBranch">Edit</a>
            <a href="deleteBranch">Delete</a>'
   );
}

$result = array(
   "draw" => $draw,
    "recordsTotal" => $query->num_rows(),
    "recordsFiltered" => $query->num_rows(),
    "data" => $data
);


echo json_encode($result);
exit();
```

}

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Branch List</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/datatables.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Branch List</h1>
    </body>

<form method="post" action="<?=site_url('main_controller/branch_page/');?>">
<table id="branch-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
   <th>Branch Code</th>
   <th>Branch Name</th>
   <th>Address</th>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Contact Number</th>
   <th>Date Created</th>
   <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php echo '<a href = "addBranch">Click Here</a> to add new branch.'; ?>

</form>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#branch-table').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url : "<?php echo site_url("main_controller/branch_page")?>",
            type : 'GET'
        },
    });
});

</script>
```

I can go to the Edit page if I write the id/branchCode manually on the URL. I've included both View and Controller. Now, how do I get it by passing it through the Edit button?
Thanks!

Comment: whee is view page code. add that in question.

Comment: Have added the view. Thanks!

Comment: in href pass required parameter thats it

Comment: $r->href='<a href="editBranch">Edit</a>
            <a href="deleteBranch">Delete</a>' You mean here? I've tried but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variable in url like below

```
foreach($query->result() as $r) 
{
   $data[] = array(
            $r->branchCode,
            $r->branchName,
            $r->address,
            $r->email,
            $r->phone,
            $r->date_created,
            $r->href=''<a href="'.site_url('main_controller/editBranch/'.$r->branchCode).'">Edit</a>
            <a href="deleteBranch">Delete</a>'
   );
}
```

You need to change url for delete as well

Comment: My main issue right now is that how do I get the brancCode for that specific row. For example if I click on Edit button for branchCode A12, then the url should be http://localhost/studyIgniter/main_controller/editBranch/A12. How do I get the "A12" to be put alongside the URL? I can't just put $r->branchcode on the href. Sorry, I'm kind of new to all these Codeigniter things.

Comment: This works perfectly!!! It takes me hours to append the branchcode to the url. Thank you very much!

Comment: But dear,how to pass id **here?** `$r->branchName`, I need code like this `<td id="22">branchName</td>`

Comment: embed the php in html. like <td id="<?php echo $r->id;?>"> Branch Name </td>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the row id or your branchCode from your table like this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('branchCode,branchName,email,phone,date_created, CONCAT(address1, " ", address2, " ", address3) AS address',FALSE)
                ->where('status','active')
                ->get('branchdetails');

$data = [];

foreach($query->result() as $r) {
   $data[] = array(
            $r->branchCode,
            $r->branchName,
            $r->address,
            $r->email,
            $r->phone,
            $r->date_created,
            $r->href='<a href="editBranch" data-code="'.$r->branchCode.'" class="linkEdit">Edit</a>
            <a href="deleteBranch" data-code="'.$r->branchCode.'" class="linkDelete">Delete</a>'
   );
}

$result = array(
   "draw" => $draw,
    "recordsTotal" => $query->num_rows(),
    "recordsFiltered" => $query->num_rows(),
    "data" => $data
);


echo json_encode($result);
exit();
```

Then you use jquery to get the data-code attribute like this:

```
$(".linkEdit").click(function(){
    editBranch($(this).attr("data-code"));
});
$(".linkDelete").click(function(){
    deleteBranch($(this).attr("data-code"));
});
```

In your editBranch and deleteBranch function you need to catch the branchCode parameter.